# how to sum a column of a queried table in sql

Tags: sql

I have this table from a query and I would like to find the sum of the Total Cost (after discount). I have searched for a solution but I can't seem to find the one I'm looking for.
Here are the sample data from my tables
Booking

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| vehicleNo |  bookingDay | driverNo | acc_status |
+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+
|        10 | 13/06/2021  |        2 | B          |
|        10 | 14/06/2021  |        0 | B          |
|        10 | 15/06/2021  |        2 | B          |
|        20 | 17/06/2021  |        2 | B          |
+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+
```

Vehicle

```
+-----------+-------------+----------------+------+
| vehicleNo |  vehicleReg |   make_model   | cost |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+------+
|        10 | IN10NGT     | Nissan R34 GTR |   90 |
|        20 | IN10MRX     | Mazda RX7      |   70 |
|        30 | IN10TSU     | Toyota Supra   |   80 |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+------+
```

Here is the query

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(Vehicle.vehicleNo) > 1, ROUND(Vehicle.cost,1) * ROUND(COUNT(Vehicle.vehicleNo) * 0.9,1), Vehicle.cost * ROUND(COUNT(Vehicle.vehicleNo),1)) AS 'Total after discount'
        FROM Booking
        INNER JOIN Vehicle
        ON Vehicle.vehicleNo = Booking.vehicleNo
        WHERE Booking.driverNo = 2
        GROUP BY Vehicle.vehicleNo
        ORDER BY Vehicle.vehicleNo;
```

an here is the result

```
+----------------------+
| Total after discount |
+----------------------+
|                  162 |
|                   70 |
+----------------------+
```

and I am expecting to have a table after calculating the sum like this

```
+----------------------+
| Overall cost         |
|after discount        |
+----------------------+
|                  232 |
+----------------------+
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of how the discount is applied, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: You can do a SELECT SUM( <conditions> ) AS ...

Comment: @BenoîtBottemanne hi, i have tried  `SELECT SUM(IF(COUNT(Vehicle.vehicleNo) > 1, ROUND(Vehicle.cost,1) * ROUND(COUNT(Vehicle.vehicleNo) * 0.9,1), Vehicle.cost * ROUND(COUNT(Vehicle.vehicleNo),1))) AS 'Total Cost'` but it gives me an "Invalid use of group function" error

Comment: @musha_muuu in that case you can do a SELECT SUM ( <SELECT original select clause with group by>)

Answer (score 0):

i have figured it out. i used this query:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM (SELECT IF(COUNT(Vehicle.vehicleNo) > 1, ROUND(Vehicle.cost,1) * ROUND(COUNT(Vehicle.vehicleNo) * 0.9,1), Vehicle.cost * ROUND(COUNT(Vehicle.vehicleNo),1)) AS Cost
        FROM Vehicle INNER JOIN Booking
        ON Vehicle.vehicleNo = Booking.vehicleNo AND Booking.driverNo = 2
        GROUP BY Vehicle.vehicleNo) AS x;
```